# How to disable editing a UITextField which uses a UIPickerView as inputView

Tags: swift

I use a UITextField as a value picker in my app. However after picking value user can cut or paste other text in this UITextField. How can I prevent this?

This is how I add picker:

```
let picker = UIPickerView()
picker.dataSource = self
picker.delegate = self

textFieldServer.inputView = picker
```

This is delegate methods for picker:

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return Servers.get.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return Servers.get[row].name
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    loginPresenter.didSetServerId(serverId: row)
    textFieldServer.text = Servers.get[row].name
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved by setting UITextField delegate like this:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```